# Pass params in google maps API url in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two params I get from a $router.push() : {{ this.$route.params.lat }} and{{ this.$route.params.lng }}. They are latitude and longitude coordinates.

I have to pass the two of them in an URL to get a Google Maps:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={{ this.$route.params.lat }},{{ this.$route.params.lng }}&zoom=15&size=300x300&maptype=terrain&key=MY_API_KEY"
```

But doing so doesn't work, I have a error message:

> Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of `<div id="{{ val }}">`, use `<div :id="val">`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion in the error message?

Comment: I've tried but didn't knew how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message indicates, you can't use the `{{ }}` template syntax within HTML attribute values.

The typical way to solve this is use the [`v-bind` syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes)

```html
<img :src="`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=${this.$route.params.lat},${this.$route.params.lng}&zoom=15&size=300x300&maptype=terrain&key=MY_API_KEY`">
```

For this though, I would use a computed property to generate the URL so you can properly handle URL encoding

```js
computed: {
  mapUrl () {
    const url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap"
    const params = new URLSearchParams({
      center: `${this.$route.params.lat},${this.$route.params.lng}`,
      zoom: 15,
      size: "300x300",
      maptype: "terrain",
      key: "MY_API_KEY"
    })
    return `${url}?${params}`
  }
}
```

Then you can use this in your template

```html
<img :src="mapUrl">
```